# Bootstrap radio-buttons toggle issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

I'm trying to turn some regular buttons in radio buttons the twitter bootstrap way (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#buttons).

I followed the instructions, but when I press the buttons I get the following error in the console:

**Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on button prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'toggle'** .

Do you know what might cause it? The buttons are loaded in the page and only become visible when the corresponding content is displayed by AJAX.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe dump question but do you have loaded `bootstrap-button.js` or `bootstrap.js` ?

Comment: bootstrap.js is loaded. I have modals on my page and they work perfectly 100% of time. The radio-buttons work like 5% of the time.

Comment: You say that the buttons are displayed only when the related content is loaded (from AJAX) right ? I'm not sure you can initialize the buttons when still hidden

Comment: Could you put your code in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: I am having this same problem, but the solutions below are not working for me. Bootstrap v3.1.0 and jQueryUI v1.10.3

Answer (score 212, accepted):

I had the same problem and it was driving me mad!!!!

Until I found that I was loading bootstrap before jqueryui...

I switched the order and notice that if I **load jqueryui BEFORE bootstrap**, I have no such problem :)

Comment: Bootstrap has a modified version of jQuery UI, and loading jQuery UI can cause troubles.

Comment: So you recommend not to have jQuery UI and Bootstrap running together?

Comment: If you are having problems, try commenting jquery ui out of the code, and if your code is working after that, jQuery UI is causing conficts.

Comment: Alexandre, if it helps, it drove me mad too until I saw this post. Thank you.

Comment: how to load jqueryui before bootstrap?

Comment: Nice catch!
KiswonoPrayogo just include jQueryUI before including bootstrap.js

Comment: Thank you for this solution!!!!! - I just wasted 3 hours try to debug this problem only to find nothing wrong other than the loading order of the scripts!!

Comment: To load jQuery UI before bootstrap.js just put your <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script> before <script src="bootstrap.js"></script> if you are running it under requirejs, add a shim :

    shim: {
     "bootstrap": {
        "deps": [
           "jquery-ui",
           "jquery"
        ]
     },
     "jquery-ui": {
        "deps": [
           "jquery"
        ]
     }
    }

Comment: Thank you Alexandre, this solved my issue. I'm using Meteor, so I had to remove jquery, and jquery-ui, and put them in my client folder.

Comment: Confirmed BS 3.1.1 and solution still stands

Comment: I am having this same problem, but this solution is not working for me.  Bootstrap v3.1.0 and jQueryUI v1.10.3

Comment: In Meteor, remove jquery-ui package, add a lib folder to your client folder, and drop jquery-ui in there. boom.

Comment: Yep, confirmed fix working for jQuery UI 1.10.4 and BS 3.0.0. **Really** annoying issue since I'm using ASP.NET MVC, and our layout pages now have to load jQuery UI for all pages even though we're only using it on a small subset since the layout pages load bootstrap. Wish I'd found this post 2 hours ago. Thanks.

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/download/ a custom bundle only with what i need, works for me.

Answer (score 7):

THis issue is due to jquery-ui blocking the initialization of Button definitions from bootstrap for users like me who have problems with shifting the order of the javascript file calls for instance when using the **CJUiAutocomplete widget in Yii**, **just shift the javascript corresponding to button.js  from the bootstrap file to the main working file and it will work smoothly.**

**Alternatively take the corresponding js and place it in a separate file that is called at the bottom of your javascript file stack.**

Answer (score 4):

Swapping the load order of Bootstrap and jQueryUI solves this problem but then it causes other issues like the Close X on jQueryUI dialogs fails to display.  Is there another way to resolve this?