# Should bootstrap.js run after jquery.js or before?

Tags: jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I want use both jquery ui and bootstrap , there is a solution 
[jquery-ui-bootstrap](https://github.com/addyosmani/jquery-ui-bootstrap)

and you must load bootstrap before jqueryui, if you won't there will apear something wrong . eg: Bialog buttons will be lose style.

[image: demo]

but there is another error when you use radio-button if you load bootstrap before jquery.
[another question about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13235578/bootstrap-radio-buttons-toggle-issue)

so? Should bootstrap.js run after jquery.js or before?

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure you should load jQuery first because Bootstrap uses jQuery features.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to load jquery.js first, and my code is runing propertly. Try it and tell us the result, otherwise, we don't know how to help you...